# How to do delete link in rails with modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am unsure of the syntax for the delete record link because I have modules for the routes

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :invites do
      collection do
        post "by_user_id"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the syntax for the delete method right now

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', invite, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Also I am using rails 4

Answer (score 1):

Please check routes via `rake routes`   DELETE method for invites resource.

Then insert your routes below in place of "your_routes_path"

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', your_routes_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```